# Spring-boot and Gradle: too long build time - how to debug?

Tags: java, spring, gradle, build, spring-boot

I have multipart project and API part of the project has around 10 dependencies.

Trying to run API project with Spring Boot(bootRun) and everything works but build time too long. I have tried to build it with gradle `parallel` and `daemon` already but it does not work.

How I can debug build process to understand what is take long time?

**Update:**

`gradle build` with **--debug** goes to this point and stack for few minutes

```
13:53:54.215 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.result.StreamingResolutionResultBuilder$RootFactory] Loaded resolution results (0.003 secs) from Binary store in /private/var/folders/jg/94cgy2fs2mqckt3mx4fj52qm0000gn/T/gradle8000416708924643404.bin (exist: true)
> Building 0% > Resolving dependencies ':web-sb-api:runtime'
```

**stack here for 2-3 minute and after that continue with really long trace...**

```
13:55:50.902 [DEBUG] [io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.exclusions.ExclusionConfiguringAction] Initial dependency graph:
13:55:50.902 [DEBUG] [io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.exclusions.ExclusionConfiguringAction] tv.accedo.appgrid:web-sb-api
13:55:50.903 [DEBUG] [io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.exclusions.ExclusionConfiguringAction]     com.newrelic.agent.java:newrelic-api
13:55:50.903 [DEBUG] [io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.exclusions.ExclusionConfiguringAction]     com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core
13:55:50.904 [DEBUG] [io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.exclusions.ExclusionConfiguringAction]     com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations
13:55:50.904 [DEBUG] [io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.exclusions.ExclusionConfiguringAction]     com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind
13:55:50.904 [DEBUG] [io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.exclusions.ExclusionConfiguringAction]         com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations
13:55:50.904 [DEBUG] [io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.exclusions.ExclusionConfiguringAction]         com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core
13:55:50.904 [DEBUG] [io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.exclusions.ExclusionConfiguringAction]     org.slf4j:slf4j-api
13:55:50.904 [DEBUG] [io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.exclusions.ExclusionConfiguringAction]     org.springframework:spring-core
13:55:50.904 [DEBUG] [io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.exclusions.ExclusionConfiguringAction]     org.springframework:spring-beans
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to run your build with `-d` or `--debug` flag to run your build with debug logging level. May be additional output will be usefull to find the reason, why your build runs so long.

Comment: @Lugaru it freezes during resolving dependencies, that could be caused by access to online resources. There is a number of articles about it over internet. You should try to run it with the `--offline` flag.

Comment: That is useful. Thanx. But still resolving dependencies takes same time.

Comment: @Lugaru you're welcome, hope you'll find the reason. I have spring boot in one of the current projects, but it takes no more, then 10-20 sec to rebuild even with a new dependencies

Comment: interesting thing spring-boot-plugin 1.3.0.RC1 build time 6 min but build with 1.2.7 plugin takes 1.5min

Comment: @Lugaru hm, may be maven caches behave different with RC versions of the libs, then with released? Interesting to see, what will be the time of the build with released version

Comment: I will write result with released version